# Program skipping a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am currently having problem with my loop. The program first asks the user to input his username and password then enters a loop wherein it compares the entered username and password with the data in the database. But the program just skips the while-loop and proceeds to the next statement.

Here is my code:

```
string user,pass,access,power , euser, epass;
char ast=' ';
int aste = 0;
ifstream account;
account.open("Account.txt");
cout<<"Username: ";cin.ignore();getline(cin,euser);
for(int i=0;i<euser.length();i++)
{
    euser[i] = toupper(euser[i]);

}
cout<<"Password: ";
do
{
ast = getch();

if (ast == 13)
{
    break;
}

if(epass.size() < 10)
{
     if(ast != 8)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        epass+=ast;
        aste ++;
    }

    else if(ast == 8 && epass.size() > 0)
    {
        cout<<"\b \b";
        epass.erase(epass.size()-1);
    }
}

else if(epass.size() == 10)
{
    if(ast == 8 && epass.size() > 0)
    {
        cout<<"\b \b";
        epass.erase(epass.size()-1);
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"";
    }
}
}while(ast!=13);


while(account>>user>>pass>>access>>power) // problem loop
{
    cout<<"hi"<<endl;
    if(euser==user && epass==pass)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Welcome "<<power<<" "<<user;
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nIncorrect username or password. Try again";
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
}

account.close();
system("pause");
```

Comment: account is the input stream

Comment: please include variable definitions.  The result of the while expression is the return value of account::operator>>(T power), so is based on the type of power.

Comment: Sidenote: in your if statement, you should really be using [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) if you're using C-style character arrays, or [string.compare()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) if you're using C++ strings, instead of the the equality comparison. If that's just pseudocode, feel free to ignore this.

Comment: by "skip the while loop", you mean that the input failed so it went onto the code after the loop? That's how C++ works.

Comment: @ScottLawson I don't see any good reason not to use `==` if the strings are `std::string`, *unless* you need the ordering information provided by `std::string::compare` . Using `==` is pretty idiomatic.

Comment: At Matt implies... if your streaming fails you should find out what exact input was in the stream (if any) that failed parsing, and eye-ball it against the parsing being attempted.  Things like a password with whitespace in it could easily cause this symptom, as could an assumption that e.g. user was numeric when it wasn't always in the input.

Comment: Is there anything in Account.txt? Does it exist? Try checking if it opens properly.

Comment: Yes there is. But when i tried to display what's inside my database, it displays nothing

Comment: @Galik DAMN! THANK YOU SO MUCH MAN. It now works *facepalm*. Changed Account.txt to Accounts.txt. That "s" whew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your code up to make it easier to debug and see what is going on:

```
account >> user;
cout << "user:" << user;
account >> pass;
cout << "pass:" << pass;
account >> access;
cout << "access:" << access;
account >> power;
cout << "power:" << power;
bool b = (bool) account;

while(b)
{
    cout<<"hi"<<endl;
    if(euser==user && epass==pass)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Welcome "<<power<<" "<<user;
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nIncorrect username or password. Try again";
        break;
    }
    system("pause");
    account >> user;
    cout << "user:" << user;
    account >> pass;
    cout << "pass:" << pass;
    account >> access;
    cout << "access:" << access;
    account >> power;
    cout << "power:" << power;
    b = (bool) account;
}
```

Note I'm not saying this is great code, just that it will help you see what is going on and  solve your problem.